# How to implement this helper method without mutating state or refactoring to class-based component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am adding a feature to the survey form review for a user to be able to upload files and my concern is that I do not want to mutate state with this implementation, how do I refactor the below to ensure this? Is my only option refactoring it to a class-based component?

```
// SurveyFormReview shows users their form inputs for review
import _ from "lodash";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import formFields from "./formFields";
import * as actions from "../../actions";

export const onFileChange = event => {
  this.setState({ file: event.target.files });
};

const SurveyFormReview = ({ onCancel, formValues, submitSurvey, history }) => {
  this.state = { file: null };

  const reviewFields = _.map(formFields, ({ name, label }) => {
    return (
      <div key={name}>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <label>{formValues[name]}</label>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Please confirm your entries</h5>
      {reviewFields}
      <h5>Add an Image</h5>
      <input
        onChange={this.onFileChange.bind(this)}
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
      />
```

Or do I have no choice except to refactor this to a class-based component as a best course?

Comment: If you're using React v16.8 or higher, you might look into the `useState` hook. Functional components can not have their own state but this hook allows you to add state to a functional component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: I second the useState. Very handy and the documentation is very thorough

Comment: @seanulus, I am using `"react": "^16.3.2",`, does that mean my best option is to refactor this into a class-based component?

Comment: If ur version is < 16.8 then yea, you should refactor this to a class with state. Personally I'm not a fan of the hook syntax. I find it to be less structured / too 1:1 with state entities. But then again I'm a fan of Typescript and more structure :D

Comment: @JohnRuddell, I am in the process of refactoring it. I would say post your comment as the answer, but I would like to provide my refactor for future viewers to see, will take suggestions best to do this so others may benefit from this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor this into a class. Something on the lines of this should work

```
class SurveyFormReview extends React.Component {
  state = { file: null };

  onFileChange = event => {
    this.setState({ file: event.target.files });
  };

  render() {
    const { onCancel, formValues, submitSurvey, history } = this.props

    const reviewFields = _.map(formFields, ({ name, label }) => {
      return (
        <div key={name}>
          <label>{label}</label>
          <label>{formValues[name]}</label>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h5>Please confirm your entries</h5>
        {reviewFields}
        <h5>Add an Image</h5>
        <input
          onChange={this.onFileChange}
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

just as a note about optimizations and stuff.

Because this is a form, I'd recommend you use better html elements.

```
const reviewFields = _.map(formFields, ({ name, label }) => {
  return (
    <fieldset key={name}>
      <span>{label}</span>
      <span>{formValues[name]}</span>
    </fieldset>
  );
});
```

`label` elements are usually used with `input` elements. 
 
`fieldset` elements are usually for form groups of data 
 
you could use a `legend` element for the title of your fieldset if you wanted :)

Comment: thanks John, there was code I did not paste so my refactor included more code, that was tedious but its done.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch existing code, you can create HOC

```
const withFile = (Component) => class extends React.Component {
  state = { file: null }
  render() {
    return <Component {...this.props} file={file} onAttach={files => this.setState({ file: files }) />
  }
}

export default withFile(SurveyForm)
```

Now your form will receive `file` and `onAttach` as props.